# How to always recommend different documents (files) in Elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, morelikethis

I have a service that recommends documents (files) relevant to the user current context. It uses ElasticSearch more_like_this in combination with filters (see query bellow). These documents are uploaded by users and if it is public, then it could be recommended to other users. It works fine, but the problem happens when two or more users upload same files. There are two or more instances of the same document in elasticsearch and it is very likely that both (or even more) files will be recommended.

Does anyone have idea how I could enforce ElasticSearch to ignore these duplicates and return only one instance of the same file?

```
POST _search
{
 "query": {
   "filtered": {
    "query": {
       "mlt": {
       "fields": [
          "file"
         ],
         "like_text": "Some sample text here",
         "min_term_freq": 1,
         "max_query_terms": 1,
         "min_doc_freq": 1
    }
  },
"filter" : {
  "or" : {
    "filters" : [ {
      "term" : {
        "visibility" : "public"
      }
    }, {
      "and" : {
        "filters" : [ {
          "term" : {
            "visibility" : "private"
          }
        }, {
          "term" : {
            "ownerId" : 2
          }
        } ]
      }
    } ]
  }
 }
 }
 },
"fields": [
  "id","title","visibility", "ownerId","contentType", "dateCreated", "url"]
}
```

**Edited:**

I solved the first part of this problem. I'm using Tika to extract the content from web page or text document. Then, I'm using it in More Like This query as like text to find most similar documents, and those having values higher then 0.9 are marked as duplicate. For this, I'm using a new field "uniqueness" which has UUID value. If new document to index is duplicate, I'm copying its "uniqueness" value, and if there is no duplicates, I'm creating new value "uniqueness" for that document.

However, the second part of the problem I still didn't solve is how to make a query that will eliminate these duplicates. So basically in above mentioned query, I have to integrate part that will choose only 1 instance of documents with the same value of field "uniqueness".

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a "duplicate" field where you can set the value to "true" or the id of a duplicate document during indexing. then you can filter out these documents.

Comment: Yes. That's a possible solution, though I was hoping to find some solution where I could search elasticsearch for distinct files. If what you suggested is applied, what would be the best approach to find duplicates of files? Using More Like This and select those results where score is close to 1.0?

Comment: That would be an option. But if your content is exactly the same, I would recommend to use a hash (MD5 for example) to find a duplicate.

Comment: That was my first idea, but I was concerned that it will not give me desired results if for example two users upload the same pdf book generated by different pdf printer so there is for example 1 letter missing in one of the books. MD5 for these files will not be the same, so I will again recommend two instances of the same book.

Comment: That's why I said: if the content is exactly the same. In your case the MoreLikeThis would be the right direction.

Comment: were you able to find a solution? i still think my response fits to your question. you need a "duplicate" field

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I could apply it, but only to some extent. I could not find solution for filtering out the duplicate documents. What I did is to add field "uniqueness" to each document. Before indexing document I check if there are similar documents, and if I find the document about threshold, new document get the same uniqueness number which means these documents are almost copies. However, I didn't find solution to always select only top scored documents between those having the same uniqueness value. I had to do that in java, which is a dirty solution and is not effective.

Comment: I couldn't apply true/false value for duplicate, because it might exclude document that might be scored better then the one that was inserted previously, so that's why I tried to go with all documents and choose only the best one.

Comment: unique and different scores, that looks really not possible to handle with a query. my approach would also be doing this outside like you did, or if you know lucene, doing that with a custom collector instance.